# Верстка блоков

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

У меня следущая ситуация : есть код html в котором есть блоки div с картинками и текстом, есть css документ в котором я задавал свойство float:left для этих блоков чтобы они обтекали друг друга. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы когда в браузере изменить ширину на определённое количество, тогда третий блок с едет вниз и станет по ширене как те два блока что остались. При это нужно чтобы картинки изменялись пропорционально окну браузера. 
Очень надо решить проблему помогите пожалуйста.

вот html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="block1" class="block">
        <p align="center" class="img_bottom"><img src="images/img1.png" alt="img1" width="260" height="150"></p>
            <p style="padding-left:125px; padding-top:10px; margin:0; padding-bottom:0;">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
            </p>
        <p class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
        <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
    </div>

    <div id="block2" class="block">
        <p align="center" class="img_bottom"><img src="images/img2.png" alt="img2" width="260" height="150" ></p>
            <p style="padding-left:125px; padding-top:10px; margin:0; padding-bottom:0;">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
            </p>
        <p class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
        <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
    </div>

    <div id="block3" class="block">
        <p align="center" class="img_bottom"><img src="images/img3.png" alt="img3" width="260" height="150"></p>
             <p style="padding-left:125px; padding-top:10px; margin:0; padding-bottom:0;">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
            </p>
        <p class="hed" class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
        <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image:url(images/bg.png); 
    background-attachment:fixed; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;

    }

#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 ;
    }

.block{
    width: 25%;
    height:300px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    min-width:190px;
    }

#block1{
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:300px;
    }

#block2{
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-top:300px;
    }

#block3{
    margin-right:100px;
    margin-top:300px;
    }

.hed{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#333333;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0; 
    padding-top:5px; 
    margin-bottom:0; 
    padding-bottom:0;
    }

.hed1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#a1a1a1;
    text-align:justify;
    word-spacing:4px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:5px;
    }
.img_bottom{
    margin-bottom:0;
    }
```

Comment: чтобы третий блок стал по ширене как те два блока что остались нужен еще и яваскрипт=)
Остальное cssом

Comment: так может кто поможет?=)

Comment: почитай про медиа запросы css...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю разберетесь. Проверил в хроме и опере. в ie появляется артефакт и картинка чуть прыгает. это можно вылечить или шириной в пикселях(а не %) или убрав селектор `.block.first` (но тогда появится справа полоса шириной в 1%) . Ну и конечно рекомендованный выше respond.js для того чтобы `@media` работало везде.

Спасибо [zhekonya](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/631/zhekonya) за идею, привык рассчитывать на ie6 ))

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}
body{
  background-image:url(images/bg.png); 
  background-attachment:fixed; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:cover;
}

#wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width:90%;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
}

/* for full wide screen*/
.block{
    /*margin: 10px; /* added*/
    height:300px;
    width: 33%;
    min-width:190px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ffffff;

    outline:1px solid red;
}
.block.first{
    width: 34%;  
}

/* for half-wide screen*/
/* max-width = 3* ( block.min-width + block.marginLeft + block.marginRight ) / #wrapper.width(90% => 0.9)) */
/* 700 =  3* (190 + 10 + 10 ) / 0.9 */
@media screen and ( max-width:700px ){ 
 /* tiny screen */
 .block,
 .block.first{
    width: 50%;  
 }

 #block3{
    outline:1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
 }
}/*/mediaquery*/

/* for tiny screen*/
/* max-width = 2* ( block.min-width + block.marginLeft + block.marginRight ) / #wrapper.width(90% => 0.9)) */
/* 467 =  2* (190 + 10 + 10 ) / 0.9 */
@media screen and ( max-width:467px ){ 
 /* tiny screen */
 .block,
 .block.first{
    width: 100%;  
    outline:1px solid blue;
 }
}/*/mediaquery*/

.hed{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#333333;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0; 
    padding-top:5px; 
    margin-bottom:0; 
    padding-bottom:0;
    }

.hed1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#a1a1a1;
    text-align:justify;
    word-spacing:4px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:5px;
}

/*added*/
.small-pic img{
  width: 32px;
}
.header-pic img{
  width: 100%;  
  max-width: 300px;
}
.cl{
  clear: both;
}
-->
</style>
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="block first">
          <p align="center" class="header-pic">
            <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif" alt="img2" />
          </p>
          <p class="small-pic" align="center">
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
          </p>
          <p class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
          <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
          <p align="center" class="header-pic">
            <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif" alt="img2" />
          </p>
          <p class="small-pic" align="center">
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
          </p>
          <p class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
          <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
      </div>

      <div id="block3" class="block">
          <p align="center" class="header-pic">
            <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif" alt="img2" />
          </p>
          <p class="small-pic" align="center">
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
              <img src="http://www.utv.bg/images/upload/web_amuse/bg.gif"/>
          </p>
          <p class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
          <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cl"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Все как по книжке Отзывчивый веб дизайн...)))

Answer (score 0):

Получится что-то вроде этого...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 660px) {
  #block1, #block2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  #block3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}/*/mediaquery*/
```

И для того что бы работало везде скачай и подключи файл [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: min-width укажи свою...это при каком минимальном размере окна браузера применить стиль, что внутри...